# May I call glDeleteShader after calling glLinkProgram?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

After I have linked my program, may I delete the shaders attached to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to the documentation: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glLinkProgram.xhtml

> The program object's information log is updated and the program is
>   generated at the time of the link operation. After the link operation,
>   applications are free to modify attached shader objects, compile
>   attached shader objects, detach shader objects, delete shader objects,
>   and attach additional shader objects. None of these operations affects
>   the information log or the program that is part of the program object.

Summarizing: "After the link operation, applications are free to ... delete shader objects. None of these operations affects... the program that is part of the program object."

This gives you more options than you might think according to theBuzzSaw's response. In particular, you are free to delete the shader, which as theBuzzSaw says, will not actually delete the shader until it is detached. But after linking, you can also detach the shader, which will allow you to *fully* delete it --- and the linked program will not be affected.

This early-deletion of the shader is used in this tutorial:

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/

(although it isn't explained directly there).

Answer (score 11):

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteShader.xml

> If a shader object to be deleted is attached to a program object, it
>   will be flagged for deletion, but it will not be deleted until it is
>   no longer attached to any program object, for any rendering context
>   (i.e., it must be detached from wherever it was attached before it
>   will be deleted).

Comment: You did not directly answer the question.

Comment: Would you feel better if I added "yes" to my answer?